# How to insert an array of floats into another array at specific index in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
matrix = array([[0.],
       [1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.]])
```

I have another array:

```
x = [0.05385944 0.05419472 0.05453447 0.05487901]
```

I would like to insert the second array into the first index of the first array such like:

```
matrix = array([[0. 0.05385944 0.05419472 0.05453447 0.05487901],
       [1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.]])
```

I have tried

```
matrix = np.insert(matrix, 1, x),
```

but this is creating an array as such:

```
array([ 0. 0.05385944, 0.05419472,  0.05453447,  0.05487901, 1., 2., 3., 4.])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy does not support variable dimensions.  So it cannot have a row that has more elements than others.

Regular Python lists can do it though:

```
matrix = [[0.],
       [1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.]]

x = [0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447, 0.05487901]

matrix[0].extend(x)

for row in matrix:print(row)

[0.0, 0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447, 0.05487901]
[1.0]
[2.0]
[3.0]
[4.0]
```

Comment: How would I create the original matrix without numpy? I am currently using 
d = range(5)
matrix = np.column_stack([d])

Comment: `matrix = [ [float(i)] for i in range(5) ]`